# Passworded ssh key suddenly does *not* require that I type the password

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh

I use console2 in combination with git bash in order to interact with my local git repositories and by extension several github and bitbucket repositories also.

I use an ssh key pair to authenticate myself to these services, howevermy ssh key pair has an associated password.

This morning I found that I was no longer required to enter this password n my laptop in order to complete the authentication process.

I did some testing and it seems that the same key present on my desktop machine still requires me to enter my password.

So my question is.... why am I no longer required to enter my password on my laptop in order to authenticate with these servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have ssh-agent (sshagent.exe) running.

It is a small utility which allows you to enter your key's passphrase once and it then holds it "unlocked" for further use without you needing to re-enter the passphrase each time. Killing it will cause the original behaviour.

ssh-agent comes along with ssh in a standard msysgit installation. I'm not sure if something's changed that now means it's used by default or not though. Another explanation as to why it's running might be if you've installed posh-git and ran a Powershell session. By default (I believe - it's been a while), it'll run at the start of the session and ask for your key's passphrase. I use it every single day with this configuration as my passphrase is quite long... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with having [git-credential-winstore](https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com) installed on your laptop?